# PHP function for convert date time to excel Number DATEVALUE conversion

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I simply want a php function to convert date to excel number format.

Ex: **2013-11-01** to **41579**

This is the way to do it in Excel

[image]

[image]

Comment: You mean to convert a PHP DateTime object or a Unix timestamp to a formatted date? Or an actual MS Excel timestamp value to a formatted date? And if you're using `PHPExcel` (as you've tagged this question) then there are built-in functions for doing this

Comment: Yes I meant to convert PHP Datetime object to excel general number format. and I'm currently not using PHPExcel. I taged it because if there is an easy way to do it using that lib, I would like to try that.

Comment: PHPExcel provides these methods in the [PHPExcel_Shared_Date class](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Shared/Date.php). The method you are looking for is [PHPToExcel()](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Shared/Date.php#L181), though the core logic is in the [FormattedPHPToExcel()](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel/Shared/Date.php#L217) method

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a way to convert a Unix timestamp to an Excel date.

```
$date_time = "2013-11-01 00:00:00";
$date_time_plus_one = strtotime($date_time . ' +1 day');
$str_date = strtotime(date('Y-m-d', $date_time_plus_one));
$excel_date = intval(25569 + $str_date / 86400);

echo 'php actual date time : ' . $date_time . '<br>';
echo 'add one day : ' . $date_time_plus_one . '<br>';
echo 'excel Number DATEVALUE : ' . $excel_date . '<br>';
```

seconds in a day: 86400 , 25569 days between 30 Dec 1899 and 01 Jan 1970. So This is the output.

> php actual date time : 2013-11-01 00:00:00
>
> add one day : 1383330600
>
> excel Number DATEVALUE : 41579

Answer (score 0):

You can change time into string like this. Every date is unique and you can also arrange them in order

```
$month = date("F");
$date = date("d");
$year = date("Y");
$timestamp = strtotime($month . " " . $date . " " . $year);
```